# Issue in sending a mail to gmail account using spring mail

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I was facing a issue while sending a mail to gmail account using spring mail. 
I referred most of the posts from stackoverflow and tried those. But no luck. Still am stuck with it. Please suggest what is still missing from my code.

Windows -8:
   Java 7

EmailServiceImpl.java:

```
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import com.test.mail.data.EmailData;

public class EmailServiceImpl {                                    
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
return mailSender;
}

public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
this.mailSender = mailSender;
}
    public void sendMail(EmailData emailData) {
    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
    try {
        helper.setFrom(emailData.getFrom());
        helper.setTo(emailData.getTo());
        helper.setSubject(emailData.getSubject());
        helper.setText(emailData.getBody());
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mailSender.send(message);
}
}
```

application-context.xml

```
            <bean id="emailSvcImpl"
                            class="com.test.mail.services.impl.EmailServiceImpl">
                            <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
                            </bean>


            <!-- via TLS -->

            <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
                            <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
                            <!-- <property name="port" value="25" /> -->  <!-- Also checked with port number : 25 -->
                            <property name="port" value="587" />
                            <property name="protocol" value="smtp" />
                            <property name="username" value="fromaccount@gmail.com" />
                            <property name="password" value="fromaccountpwd" />
                            <property name="javaMailProperties">
                                            <props>
                                                            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                                                            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                                                            <prop key="mail.smtp.debug">true</prop>
                                                            <prop key="mail.smtp.timeout">8500</prop>
                                            </props>
                            </property>
            </bean>


            <!-- Also Tried  to send gmail via SSL -->
            <!-- 
            <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
                            <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
                            <property name="port" value="465" />
                            <property name="protocol" value="smtps" />
                            <property name="username" value="fromaccount@gmail.com" />
                            <property name="password" value="fromaccountpwd" />
                <property name="javaMailProperties">
                  <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
                 <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                   <prop key="mail.smtps.debug">true</prop>
                      <prop key="mail.smtps.timeout">8500</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
            </bean>  -->
```

Maven dependencies:

```
            <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                       <version>3.2.11.RELEASE</version>
             </dependency>

            <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
                 <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
                 <version>1.5.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

cmd prompt: used'ping smtp.gmail.com' command to ping , am able to get the reply and no loss of data.

Exception :

```
   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,   port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
           java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
           java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Tried sending mail with SSL and TLS , but same exception with different port numbers

Comment: Is smtp.gmail.com on port 465 reachable from your computer?

Comment: @Jens: How to test that whether smtp.gmail.com on port 465 rechable or not from my computer..

Comment: You can use `telnet`.

Comment: you wanna try me this command - 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 465"

Comment: @Jens: C:\Users\afjali>telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 465: Connect failed

Comment: Looks like you can not connect. Maybe it is blocked by a firewall.

Comment: @Jens: I checked my firewall settings. it is in turned off mode

Answer (score 4):

Google has changed the policies, you need to allow your account to be accessed by applications.

I came across an issue yesterday and received this email via google.com

You can switch to an app made by Google such as Gmail to access your account (recommended) or change your settings at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps so that your account is no longer protected by modern security standards.

once you are done with is all, you can verify the properties, this is what I have used and it is working perfectly on my end

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); //SSL Port
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
 "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); //SSL Factory Class
 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //Enabling SMTP Authentication
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); //SMTP Port
```

I hope you are using the correct values.

Comment: I followed as per your suggested answer, but still getting same error

Comment: <property name="port" value="587" /> did you try 465?

Comment: for which configuration - via TLS or via SSL congiuration in my application-context.xml

Comment: i changed from smtps to smtp..but no use

Comment: Yes..i have changed all of them to smtp..Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;

Comment: I also tried the example from this link : http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/. Getting Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587. Tried the same example with port 465 . But sameexception with port 465

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a firewall on your network preventing you from connecting.  You may need to [configure JavaMail to work through your proxy server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy).

FYI, [connection debugging tips are also in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).